# Revit API - Can't paint generated Direct Shapes

Tags: c#, triangulation, vertex, revit-api, face

I generate all of them the same, but some of them can't be colored (image on the bottom)

Steps:

1. I'm creating list of faces from solid

   ```
   internal static List<List<XYZ>> GetFacesFromSolidTriangulate(Solid geomSolid)
   {
       List<List<XYZ>> faces = new List<List<XYZ>>();

       foreach (Face face in geomSolid.Faces)
       {
           Mesh mesh_space = face.Triangulate();

           for (int i = 0; i < mesh_space.NumTriangles; i++)
           {
               MeshTriangle triangle = mesh_space.get_Triangle(i);

               XYZ p1 = triangle.get_Vertex(0);
               XYZ p2 = triangle.get_Vertex(1);
               XYZ p3 = triangle.get_Vertex(2);
               List<XYZ> xyz = new List<XYZ>();

               xyz.Add(triangle.get_Vertex(0));
               xyz.Add(triangle.get_Vertex(1));
               xyz.Add(triangle.get_Vertex(2));

               faces.Add(xyz);
           }
       }

       return faces;
   }
   ```
2. I'm creating Direct Shape using

   ```
   static public DirectShape NewDrawDirectShape(Document doc, List<List<XYZ>> faces, ElementId matId, string name)
   {
       TessellatedShapeBuilder builder = new TessellatedShapeBuilder();
       builder.OpenConnectedFaceSet(true);

       foreach(List<XYZ> face in faces)
       {
           builder.AddFace(new TessellatedFace(face, matId));
       }

       builder.CloseConnectedFaceSet();
       builder.Build();

       TessellatedShapeBuilderResult result = builder.GetBuildResult();

       DirectShape ds = DirectShape.CreateElement(doc, new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_GenericModel));

       ds.SetShape(result.GetGeometricalObjects());
       ds.Name = name;

       return ds;
   }
   ```

And here is the problem, I can't paint few of them even using Revit "paint" tool...
Red arrow define what I'm trying achieve on this direct shape, blue direct shapes works correctly

[image]

Comment: In your code snippet nr. 1, you are not using `p1`, `p2` and `p3`, so you could shorten and clarify by deleting them.

Comment: @JeremyTammik after I deleted really small triangles, the final results is much better. Now I have only one DirectShape which I can't paint so probably triangulate functionreturns bad triangles.

Comment: Glad to hear you have the problem almost completely solved.

Comment: Thank God I found your question and learned about TessellatedShapeBuilder. I was about to create my own triangulation engine to make surface from Area boundaries

Comment: Great that helped you Dmitriy :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the triangle orientations? Maybe some of the triangles returned in the `MeshTriangle` objects are incorrectly oriented. To try it out, you could create a little model line in the centre of each triangle indicating its normal vector and this the edge orientation.

Comment: yup, I tried this. I checked normal after calculating this 3 points. All of them have (0,0,1) I also tried reverse them all, but no matter what I do final results are the same.